# How to remove camplz virus on ubuntu

Tags: malware

I have noticed a virus on our machine. Symptoms it shows are

1. It runs multiple process with the name camplz. If I kill the process
   it restarts
2. The executable is present under /usr/bin directory. If I
   delete the executable it gets recreated.
3. It creates files under /tmp
   with name config.f and ??af???a???mdkkkk.
4. If I delete the files,
   they are recreated It ESTABLISH IP connections to China based IP
   addresses and starts sending bytes in MB, increasing my bandwidth
   utilization.

   ```
   lsof -o shows camplz  26983    root    2u  IPv4 2380650457      0t0  TCP <mydomain.com>:18703->100.42.227.29:18888 (ESTABLISHED)
   ```

mydomain.com is a placeholder.

Although, I have found the source, I do not have idea on how to remove it and clean my machine. I do not want to change machine as much as possible. At present, I have written a simple script that kills the process and deletes the files created. This helps. However it is not a permanent solution. I used few virus scanning software. But they do not catch. Can someone suggest a solution.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    while true; do ps -ef | grep camplz | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |  xargs kill; rm /usr/bin/camplz ; rm /tmp/config.f ; rm /tmp/??af???a???mdkkkk ;  done
```

Comment: Ubuntu is free to install or reinstall, so backup data, and reinstall.

Comment: As a stopgap, you might be able to remove `/usr/bin/camplz`, create a new file of your own creation in its place (even for example a zero-byte file), and then make it immutable with `chattr +i /usr/bin/camplz`.  This will not clean out your system, but may at least stave off one of the symptoms while you seek a complete solution.

Comment: The number `26983` there is the proces ID.  So try doing this: `ps -e -o cmd,pid,ppid | grep 26983` . It will show you 3 things - command, it's PID, and its parent PID. Repeat this for parent PID. That way you know *what starts that process* and maybe will give you an idea how to stop it from reappearing.  Of course, each time the PID number is different, so make sure you check with `lsof ` fist

Comment: @Serg tried... Looks like it changes the parent process ID to 1. Output is <code> ps -e -o cmd,pid,ppid | grep 12647
camplz                      12647     1
grep --color=auto 12647     13126  2415</code>

Comment: @Amol  OK,  so it seems it's  started by PID 1, which is init.  That probably  means it is in one of the system services.  Probably  you  will need to recursively  search folders with system scripts.  What system  version you have?  16.04 ?

Comment: @Serg Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Comment: OK , do this : `sudo grep -iR 'campiz' /etc/init*` . If you get any listing, you can paste it to paste.ubuntu.com and provide link here

Comment: @Serg grep -iR 'campiz' /etc/init* returned empty. Then I tried grep -rnw '/' -e "camplz"
the output of the command is pasted on http://paste.ubuntu.com/23098918/ looks like /usr/share/man/man3/ast.gz  and /usr/bin/.zip.swp  are infected. Not sure about other two outputs.

Comment: @Amol indeed, those appear to be masqueraded as archives, but it's `.zip`, a hidden file, and there's no legitimate reason to have hidden files in /usr/bin/ I think you can safely remove them.

Comment: `/usr/bin/acpid` is somewhat suspicious too. What does `file /usr/bin/acpid` tell you ?

Comment: Ok. I deleted  `/usr/bin/.zip.swp` and `/usr/bin/.zip.swp`... Now camplz does not restart. I am monitoring it. Hoping that this acts as a fix.

Comment: acpid seems to be system command 'Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon' http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/acpid.8.html

Comment: Intrestingly, while monitoring, I noticed cp command being run that copies ast.gz to camplz in bin folder. `ps -ef | grep camplz
root      7615  2415  1 Aug27 pts/1    00:01:04 grep --color=auto -rnw / -e camplz
root     31947 27067  0 00:37 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto camplz
root     31963  1049  0 00:37 ?        00:00:00 cp /usr/share/man/man3/ast.gz /usr/bin/camplz` But it has failed...  and 1049 is `root      1049     1  0 Aug27 ?        00:07:02 bash /usr/bin/dbus/dbus-daemon-draw` I killed it too.

Comment: More progress... Both acpid and dbus-daemon-draw are the scripts inserted by virus. They run in loop and copy /usr/share/man/man3/ast.gz to /usr/bin/camplz . @Serg you were right in suspecting acpid. The scripts are pasted on http://paste.ubuntu.com/23099095/ ... I have deleted all 4 files 
`/usr/share/man/man3/ast.gz /usr/bin/acpid /usr/bin/camplz /usr/bin/.zip.swp /usr/bin/dbus/dbus-daemon-draw`

Answer (score 2):

Friends,
Monitored the system last night and found it stable. Thought of sharing my experience on how the problem was solved.

**Problem statement**
Got email from hosting provider that bandwidth usage has increased multifold.

**Hunting for source**

1. Ran `iftop -n` to find out the flow of data. Clearly my machine was
   sending data out.
2. Ran `lsof -i` and `lsof -o` to find out which
   process are sending data out.
3. Got the PID from output of `lsof -o`
4. Ran `ps -e -o cmd,pid,ppid | grep <pid>` to understand the parent
   process id. It was found to be 1
5. Ran `grep -rnw '/' -e "camplz"` to
   find out all the files that had presence of name of the process
6. Opened the files to read how the scripts were behaving
7. Ultimately deleted all the infectious files and killed their running
   process

More specific information points are in the comments. I believe they could defer for individuals though.

Wrote few scripts during this process. Hope you find them useful.

**Script to kill the process whenever it appears**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    while true; do ps -ef | grep camplz | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |  xargs kill; rm /usr/bin/camplz ; rm /tmp/config.f ; rm /tmp/??af???a???mdkkkk ;  done
```

**Script to monitor bandwidth usage and send email in case it jumps**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    log="/root/net.log"
    current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
            echo
            echo usage: $0 network-interface
            echo
            echo e.g. $0 eth0
            echo
            echo shows packets-per-second
            exit
    fi

    IF=$1

    while :;
    do
            R1=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/rx_bytes`
            T1=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/tx_bytes`
            sleep 10
            R2=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/rx_bytes`
            T2=`cat /sys/class/net/$1/statistics/tx_bytes`
            TXPPS=`expr $T2 - $T1`
            RXPPS=`expr $R2 - $R1`
            echo "tx $1: $TXPPS bytes/s rx $1: $RXPPS bytes/s"
                    if [ "$TXPPS" -gt 100000000 ]; then
                    mail -s "Data is being transmitted above 100 MB. Please Check" <put your email id here. e.g. me@mycompany.com> < /dev/null
                            echo "$current_time Mail send successfully" >>$log
                    fi
    done
```

Thanks to @mikewhatever @DopeGhoti and special thanks to @Serg